# How can I remove a release from publishing overview (google play console)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I want to remove the production Start full rollout from the publishing overview page because I don't want to publish my app yet to production.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T88DV.png)

I tried looking into the Production tab and Publishing Overview but I can't find how to remove it anywhere.

Comment: When you send the app for review there is an option to remove changes in the publishing overview. If it is not sent for review then you can upload the correct version of the app.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Much appreciated.

However, the app is ready to send for review and I don't want it inside that category because when I make other changes I want to send for review I don't want the production to go through as well.

Comment: Okay. You can discard the release. After discarding the release you can submit the other changes for review.